# Generic Loop for Restaurant menu

Tags: python, loops

python noobie here. For a practice question in school I'm suppose to make a restaurant menu. The user is suppose to enter in their name and go through the procedures of making a sandwich, after checking to see if the users name is valid first. The question asks us to make a menu function which is suppose to take the paramaters of the choiceList, minimum choices and maximum choices.

Example: Ask the user how many toppings they'd like on their sandwich. With a minimum value of at least 1 topping and max 3 toppings.

What I don't understand is how I'm suppose to make a generic loop to loop through these separate list's without hard coding in the values given. I hope this makes sense I tried to word it my best but here is an example of what it's suppose to look like and my code.

Example [image: Output Example of what it's suppose to look like]

```
# Input:
# user's name
# wrapper choice (min 1, max 1)
# protein choice (min 1, max 1)
# toppings choices (min 1, max 3)
# sauce choice (min 0, max 1)

# Processing:

# Output:
# User's name followed by their protein choice, wrapper choice, toppings choices, and sauce.

def menuModule( choiceList, minimumChoices, maximumChoices ):
    order = []
    index = 0

    for i in choiceList:
        index = index + 1 
        print( i )
        choice = input( "What is your choice?" )

        if choice == index:
            order.append( choiceList[index] )

dirtyNames = [ "mud", "dirt", "dust", "booger", "diaper" ]
valid = True
wrapChoices = [ "[1]sesame seed bun", "[2]soft tortilla shell" ]
proteinChoices = [ "[1]chicken", "[2]beef", "[3]tofu" ]
toppingChoices = [ "[1]tomato", "[2]lettuce", "[3]pickles", "[4]cheese", "[5]onions" ]
sauceChoices = [ "[1]ketchup", "[2]mayonaise", "[3]McCalorie Secret Sauce" ]


while valid:
    name = str( input( "What is your name? " ) )
    if name in dirtyNames:
        print( "I'm sorry, that name is not allowed at McThoseguys." )
        continue
    elif name.isdecimal() is True:
        print( "I'm sorry, that is not a name." )
        continue
    elif any( substring in name.lower() for substring in dirtyNames ):
        print( "I'm sorry, that name is not allowed at McThoseguys." )
    else:
        print( "Hello " + name + ", welcome to McThoseguys!" )
        valid = False
        menuModule( wrapChoices, 1, 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **while valid** loop is the right concept.  This handles *one* of the menus.  Now, you need a *second* loop around that to cycle through the various list sections, and a larger list of lists to hold the menu.

```
menu_sections = [
                 wrapChoices,
                 proteinChoices,
                 toppingChoices,
                 sauceChoices
                ]

for section in menu_sections:
    valid_choice = False
    while !valid_choice:
        # Get user's choice
        # Check validity ... if choice <= len(section)
```

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

This is a small snippet of code running:

```
toppingChoices = [ (1,"tomato"), (2,"lettuce"), (3,"pickles"), (4,"cheese"), (5,"onions") ]

def menuModule( choiceList, minimumChoices, maximumChoices ):
    order = []
    num_choices = 0
    choices_dict = dict(choiceList)
    for choice_index in choices_dict:
        print("[{}] {}".format(choice_index, choices_dict[choice_index]))

    while num_choices < maximumChoices:
        choice = input("What is your choice? Type q to exit: ")
        if choice is "q" and num_choices >= minimumChoices:
            break
        elif choice is "q" and num_choices < minimumChoices:
            print("You must select at least {} items".format(minimumChoices))
            continue

        if int(choice) in choices_dict.keys():
            num_choices += 1
            order += [choices_dict[int(choice)]]
        else:
            print("Choice is not in the list")

    print(order)


menuModule(toppingChoices, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that **while valid** is a good concept for this kind of input.

Avoid having `[1]tomatoes, [2]onions` numeric markings within the list items, it's not a good practice. It's better to add them when printing the actual item names, like

`for item in choice_list:
        print ("["+str(index)+"] "+ item)
        index += 1`

```
[1] sesame seed bun
[2] soft tortilla shell
```

In case you decide to use () instead of [ ] one day will be a lot easier to maintain ;)

Also, you can try recursion on this as well, maybe first adding all choices functions with their parameters to a separate list, something like:

```
choices = [(wrapChoices, 1, 1), (proteinChoices, 1, 1), (toppingChoices, 1, 3), (sauceChoices, 0, 1)]
```

Then in the definition, you can add 'idx' parameter so you can call the function from itself, like:

```
def menuModule(choice_list, minimumChoices, maximumChoices, idx):

...
# and call it at the end again with
 idx += 1
 menuModule(*choices[idx], idx)
```

This way you can cycle through all choices, but will need to exit when idx reaches length of choices.

As a practice, maybe it's better you make separate functions for each choice first and then later try and make them 'generic'

hope it helps a bit!